# PHP - in built function to populate an array with specific elements from another array

Tags: php, arrays, fill

I have a list of objects ( Cars ) so cars[0]->getId() is 12, cars[1]->getId is 25 etc. I want to fill an array with these IDs without using foreach

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
$carIds = array()
foreach ($cars as $car) {
   $carIds[] = $car->getId();
}
```

Is there an in built function to directly populate the array?

Comment: Is there a reason why not using the `foreach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php
Sample code:

```
$result = array_map(function ($car) {
  return $car->getId();
}, $cars);
```